# ios/xcode: What is Best way to launch view controller from action sheet?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to launch different view controllers from an action sheet.

Is it best practice to create the view controllers in storyboard and then using the identifier, launch them from the appropriate point in the action sheet?

I am trying to get following to work without success.  It is saying I need to define window property...

```
-(void)launchVC {

 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"reportProblem"];
    [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:ivc animated:NO completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"should have launched by now");
}
```

Alternatively, is it better to create the whole view controller in code?

FYI, I am leaning toward storyboard as this view controller has its own class and I know how to set class in storyboard but not in code but cannot get it to work.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you implemented `launchVC` method ?

If you have implemented `launchVC` method in your `AppDelegate`, then it should work.

Otherwise If you have implemented it in your `ViewController` Class then

```
[self presentViewController:ivc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: this compiles however the app does not launch the view controller I created in storyboard with the storyboard id reportProblem.  Am going to try embedding it in a nav controller

Comment: Where have you implemented launchVC method ?

Comment: Your code was launching VC.  I just needed to tweak it to launch navigation controller.  Thx.